# Formatting ampersand adds unexpected characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, djoser

Using [Djoser](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser) Im trying to generate right url for my frontend. I have to have ampersand in my url string and Djoser do format this url before sending it to my frontend. The url looks like:

```
https://localhost:4200/activate?id=MjA&token=540-cad5f834d5508ebdd78e
```

But the final result that I get looks like **note "amp;" after &**:

```
http://localhost:4200/activate?id=MjE&amp;token=541-c0437e0afd6261fd4833
```

I tried following solutions but none of them works `(\u0026, {\u0026}, {\u0026:c}, &&)`:

```
print("https://localhost:4200/activate?id={uid}\u0026token={token}".format(uid="MjA", token="540-cad5f834d5508ebdd78e"))
print("https://localhost:4200/activate?id={uid}{\u0026}token={token}".format(uid="MjA", token="540-cad5f834d5508ebdd78e")) <-- returns KeyError: '&'
print("https://localhost:4200/activate?id={uid}{\u0026:c}token={token}".format(uid="MjA", token="540-cad5f834d5508ebdd78e")) <-- returns KeyError: '&'
```

**NOTE:** I can't directly change code in `format()` part, this will be handled by Djoser. The part that I can pass is actually only assign the string value to activation url like there: `'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate?id={uid}{\u0026:c}token={token}',` So I have to write my solution in this string.

**NOTE2:** I tried it in jupiter, there all works fine, I get the right url when I do it this way:

```
print("https://localhost:4200/activate?id={uid}\u0026token={token}".format(uid="MjA", token="540-cad5f834d5508ebdd78e"))
```

[image]

Directly adding `&` returns to frontend same url with `amp;` behind `&`

**UPDATE**
Djoser template overwriting

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    },
]
```

[image]

Comment: Something is HTML escaping the url, which is why it's being converted.  I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, so I'm not sure if turning off that escaping is the right answer or not.

Comment: what do you mean with "escaping"?  the backslash?

Comment: Im trying to generate user activation url.

In this line djoser formats the url https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/9baf4384a46071e8961f04a52d0c7ed889f8d354/djoser/email.py#L18

and there it will be shown https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/9baf4384a46071e8961f04a52d0c7ed889f8d354/djoser/templates/email/activation.html#L11

Comment: I mean that HTML treats "&" specially, so when you want a literal ampersand, it has to be encoded as "&amp;".  The latter bit as actually called an "HTML Entity" and the "&" is the leading character for describing an entity, hence the reason a literal ampersand needs to be written as "&amp;".  Now that I see what's going on, it's the Django template engine that's escaping the ampersand.  In the template, `{{ url }}` needs to be `{{ url|safe }}`.  It's been a while since I've done this in Django, but I believe you can create a site template to override the one in Djoser.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you, I have now to find out how to override the djoser template.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/overriding-templates.html#overriding-from-the-project-s-templates-directory).

Comment: I have tried to catch the djoser template path. Created different paths but can't overwrite the template. Or I do that,  but `{{ url|safe }}` does not work.

Comment: First, try changing the template in a more obvious way so that it's easy to tell if you're overriding it.  Second, you need to follow the directions in the link I provided and put it in the appropriate templates directory.  Say that directory is called "templates".  You would need to create a template at "templates/email/activation.html" with the changes you want.  Finally, make sure you do things in the right order, because order definitely matters.  You want Django to find your site template before the one in Djoser.  Hope that helps!

Comment: The one highlighted in your picture is the one you need.  How do I know that?  Because of [this line](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/9baf4384a46071e8961f04a52d0c7ed889f8d354/djoser/email.py#L10).

Comment: yeah all the templates are overwritten, but Ill change the djoser default one and try it. Then if it will work find the way to overwrite it. Thank you very much

Comment: Exactly! It works!!! Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some back and forth discussion, it turns out that Djoser wants to send an activation email and the contents are being generated from [a Django template](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/9baf4384a46071e8961f04a52d0c7ed889f8d354/djoser/templates/email/activation.html#L11).  The issue is that Django does HTML escaping by default, so the `&` character is being converted to an HTML entity, `&amp;`, which is not what is desired here.

The answer is to mark the url as being HTML safe by piping it through a filter.  This effectively means replacing `{{ url }}` with `{{ url|safe }}`.  The best way to do this is to create a new template to override the one provided by Djoser and put in the required content.  This template needs to reside in the project templates area as "email/activation.html".  There is some documentation in Django on [how this is done](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/overriding-templates.html#overriding-from-the-project-s-templates-directory) too.

Once the template is working correctly, then the url should be emitted directly with no escaping.